# Karate : dynamic test data using scenario outline is not working in some cases

Tags: karate

I was tryiny to solve dynamic test data problem using dynamic scenario outline as mentioned in the documentation https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline
It worked perfectly fine when I passed something like this in Example section

> Examples:
> |[{'entity':country},{'entity':state},{'entity':district},{'entity':corporation}]]
> But I tried to generate this json object programatically , I am getting aa strange error
>
> WARN  com.intuit.karate - ignoring dynamic expression, did not evaluate to list: users - [type: MAP, value: com.intuit.karate.ScriptObjectMap@2b8bb184]

Code to generate json object

```
    * def user =
    """
      function(response){

        entity_type_ids =[]
        var entityTypes = response.entityTypes
        for(var i =0;i<entityTypes.length;i++ ){
          object = {}
          object['entity'] = entityTypes[i].id
          entity_type_ids.push(object)
        }
        return JSON.stringify(entity_type_ids)
      }
    """
```

Comment: I'm sorry I can't diagnose this from what you've given. I also have to say that you never need to use JS loops in karate, and especially never need to call `JSON.stringify()`. please spend some time reading the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#loops - and if you still need help, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thank you.  JSON.stringify() ----> I was trying differnt things when most obvious things were not working :) [ when you loose  'kuntham' you ended up searching everywhere  :) ]     My issue got resolved when I changed my example to 
    Examples:
    |allEntityTypes.entityTypeIds|